# How to set multiple currency and geo location with algolia search in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, algolia

We're using algolia for our website with woocommerce. We've used currency switcher plugin on which works with geolocation but on search and category pages where data comes from algolia it doesn't change the price there and show base currency.

So, how can we enable geolocation with algolia and set multi currency based on Geo location?

I've tested most of the plugins. they work but just not on the algolia result page. so looking for a solution which can also work on algolia result page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Algolia plugin doesn't support any multi-currency plugin. If you want to make it work you will have to edit Algolia's plugin.

The solution would really depend on how the multi-currency plugin works:

- if the plugin is able to figure out the conversion in the browser, then chances are you can work something out quickly by editing the template file.
- If everything happens in the backend, you would need to figure out how to get all currencies and push them along every product record.

In general, I think it's easier to index the price in each currency and display it without calculation in the template.